# How to parse a string to date and back to string with same format

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having a problem with dates (what a surprise), can someone help me? Here are the steps I follow.

Comment: "`datepipe`" is the DatePipe library from Angular.

1. `var date = new Date('2020-12-31');`
2. `var stringDate = this.datepipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));`
3. Output: '`2020-12-30`'.

Why is this happening, why is taking one day off? This is just happening with some timezones like in New York, this is not happening the Spain's timezone.

Any idea? Any possible solution?

Thanks,

Oriol López

Comment: Have you tried passing the 3rd parameter of a timezone? `.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'GMT-3')` or in html `<span>{{myDate|date:'yyyy-MM-dd':'GMT-3'}}</span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding `T00:00:00` at the end of the date fixes the problem.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    var date = new Date('2020-12-31' + 'T00:00:00');
    var stringDate = this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
    alert(stringDate);
  }
}
```